# How to merge a sql result that joins tables into a proper object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a query that joins 2 tables and returns this result:

[image]

This is due to the Left Join that I do on my query.  Progmatically, to turn this into one object I do the following:

```
 clsJobPosting JobPosting = new clsJobPosting();
    DataSet dsJobs = JobPosting.SelectForAllJobs(clsSession.UserID, startRowIndex, pageSize, orderBy, orderByDirection, categoryId);


    DataTable dtJobs = dsJobs.Tables[0];

    List<JobItem> jobPostings = new List<JobItem>();

    DataRow[] arrFileInfo;
    FileCountItem FileInfoItem;
foreach (DataRow drJob in dtJobs.Rows)
    {
        JobItem jobPost = new JobItem(drJob, CallingPageName.AllQuestions);
        jobPost.TotalRecords = totalRecords;
        jobPost.FileItems = new List<FileCountItem>();
        if (jobPostings.Any(x =>  x.JobId == jobPost.JobId))
        {

            JobItem jobItem = jobPostings.Single(s=>s.JobId == jobPost.JobId);

            jobItem.Tags.Add(jobPost.CategoryName);
            jobPost.Tags = jobItem.Tags;
            jobPostings.Remove(jobItem);

            jobPostings.Add(jobPost);

        }else{
        arrFileInfo = dtFileInfo.Select("JobId = " + jobPost.JobId);
        for (int j = 0; j < arrFileInfo.Length; j++)
        {
            FileInfoItem = new FileCountItem(arrFileInfo[j]);
            jobPost.FileItems.Add(FileInfoItem);
        }
        string CategoryName = jobPost.CategoryName;
        jobPost.Tags.Add(CategoryName);
        jobPostings.Add(jobPost);
        }
    }
```

I basically turn the data into an object that has a property called `Tags` and it is a `List<string>` where I store the different CategoreyNames.  Essentially, I am merging this data into one object with the different CategoryNames in a list.  Is there a better way to merge this data?  I feel like this is way too extensive to merge the data.  I am not sure how `GROUP BY` would work in the query also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try LINQ to SQL to create the properties of a class against the columns returned from the Stored Procedure. The following is a link which will guide you through the same.

[LINQ to SQL for Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use  Group by and then SelectMany and then string.join to come up categaryname tags for each claasified id .